# save R objects in the background using R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, directory, save, reactive

i want to save R-object using R-Shiny-App. The with the normal Download Button you can save files, but have to define a directory every time. I want to save R-Objects without asking for the directory.

i tried the naive way using a reactive Button, doesnt work

For example to save this vector inside of a reactive value...

```
library(shiny)

vec <- c(1,2,3,4)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("saveData", "Save")
)

server <- function(input,output,session) {


  vec <- reactive({
    vec <- c(1,2,3,4)
    vec
  })

  observeEvent(input$saveData,{
    save(vec(), file = 'vec.RData')
  })

}
shinyApp(server = server, ui = ui)
```

same problem while trying to create and delete folders. I tink the problem is the function eventReactive() because it tries to give out a object, but cant. is there any other function i could use?

Comment: Hi, please include a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it will be easier to help you with that

Comment: I don't see why it would not work with `eventReactive` but it would be more appropriate to use `observeEvent` instead. Anyway, you should edit your question to include a minimal reproducible example, so that we can see exactly what you do.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, that does not work with `eventReactive`. Use `observeEvent` instead. Moreover, in the `save` function, we provide the objects to be saved, but *by their names*. If you do `save(vec(), file = "vec.RData")`, then the `save` function will search for an object named `vec()`. So you should do something like:

```
  observeEvent(input$saveData,{
    x <- vec()
    save(x, file = 'vec.RData')
  })
```

I would recommend `saveRDS` to save a single R object.